# Azure/Node.js Unaught exception: Error: Cannot find module 'ms'

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2015

I’ve deployed a small node.js app that runs fine locally in visual studio 2015 to Azure using the Azure publish option (right click – publish – azure profile etc.).
However, when I visit the site all I get on the page is:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

If I connect VS server explorer up to the Azure instance to view the logs, inside logging-errors.txt I can see the following logged lots of times:

```
Wed Jul 29 2015 12:22:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Unaught exception: Error: Cannot find module 'ms'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\debug\debug.js:14:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

This is a brand new web app provisioned via the preview portal.

There is no ‘ms’ package defined either in my project dependencies or in the node_modules folder, so I'm assuming this is a Microsoft/Azure specific package required for hosting on Azure.

Have I missed a step in “preparing” my node app for Azure, or is there some other configuarion step I need to perform?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's having trouble loading modules. Do you have a package.json file that defines your dependencies? The default deployment script that Azure runs when you deploy your site will look for a package.json and perform an `npm install --production`. That means it will install everything you've defined as in 'dependencies' but not the packages you've defined as 'devDependencies'.

Answer (score 0):

To debug node apps deployed to Azure that won't startup I do:

- Open a Powershell on it's scm (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell)
- Check your node is set correctly `node --version`
- Attempt to start it and look at errors `node .\server.js` (or whatever is specified in your `package.json > start` script.

It would be nice if you could see such a log for when Azure starts the app.  However I have not found it.