# Error: Cannot find module 'ms'

Tags: node.js, module

I've been trying to get my app running for a few days now, but keep getting errors. I'm closer than I have been so far, but am now getting the **"Cannot find module error"** when trying to launch my application.

Below is the error I'm getting now.

```
C:\MY-APP\dataService>node dataAPI.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ms'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MY-APP\node_modules\express\node_modules\debug
\debug.js:14:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

I also searched the forums for an answer to this question and [found this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700589/azure-node-js-unaught-exception-error-cannot-find-module-ms), but it was in reference to Azure, which I'm not using.

I'm new to Node.js so forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about because that's largely the truth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please see this Link :
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms**

and use :

npm install ms -S

on your project its automatically save ms package to the node-module.

Comment: Is that what the -S is for? I found once I installed "ms" I have a bunch of other dependencies it's looking for. Thanks for sending me in the right direction. So should I add -S to all modules I want in my node-module directory?

Comment: -S is used for set dependency on package JSON for next time use.

Comment: Goctha. Thanks so much Nitesh.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the above answer doesn't work for someone with this problem: I had this same problem when trying to run tests using the Puppeteer framework. I ended up having to cd into the `node_modules/puppeteer` folder and manually running `npm install` for it to finally work in my case.